# Fetch wordpress video attachment with post ID

Tags: theme-development, attachments

So I have wasted 5 hours of my life to figure how to fetch wordpress custom post videos and been unsuccessful and here i am. Looking for expert advice.

My Requirement: 
- Fetch all video attachments of a custom post.
- Display all videos url in frontend by a foreach loop with the post ID with custom html and css.

What I did:

```
- Everything
- get_attached_media('video', $post_ID); // didn't work
- wp_query(.. with arguements) //didn't work
- get_post(with argument on post_type=attachment and post_parent = $post_id) // didn't work
-get_children (with argument on post_type=attachment and post_parent = $post_id) // didn't work
```

What i get : 
    - Image can be retrived but not videos..

Help me understand how it is done?

Comment: And you are sure you spelled `video` correctly?

Comment: Are the video URL's being added as custom field(s)? If so, are you using wordpress custom fields or ACF?

Comment: Are you certain the videos are *attached* to the post? Just using the video somewhere in the post isn't enough to be 'attached'. To be attached the video has to have been uploaded directly to that post.

Comment: Yea i added from Add Media button. Just like i added image. I an get the image but not the video. The video is added dirctly on the editor via add media no custom field used.